# Winter Bash in Summer?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, internationalization

I'm proudly wearing my Winter Hat, in Summer! (at least in my country) According to the official [mini website](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year

Isn't there a better name to include all the SO users around the world in the new year celebration that aren't in Winter?

Comment: Solution: let's have winter bash in June as well! That way, everyone gets winter bash during winter :)

Comment: ["As in the past, tradition defeated accuracy in the naming decision. Hopefully some of our summertime audience will be at least partially mollified by the fact that the Winter Bash site will be available in Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese and Russian this year, thanks to the efforts of our international Community Managers."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/)

Comment: What would you call it?  They had to call it something.  It's not the New Year for everyone.  Not everyone celebrates Christmas or Hanukkah or any of the other december holidays?  Should we call it [Festivus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festivus) Bash.

Comment: I would like to see the arguments for downvoting the question.

Comment: @resueman while not agreeing with the result, I'm glad to see that the topic has been already discussed at least.

Comment: @psubsee2003 New Year's bash is way more inclusive than Winter bash.

Comment: @marcanuy I think you need to come up with sometihng more to defend that.  I do not know the accuracy of these numbers, but I've seen stats that suggest 90% of the population is in the northern hemisphere.  So winter sounds very inclusive to me.

Comment: How about Bash Bash?

Comment: @JoeMalpass I like that, if not we have a recursive acronym WBW (Winter Bash maybe not Winter) GNU style.

Comment: let the sun set at 4am that I can get a good night's sleep!!

Comment: How about serving different content for IPs from Southern hemisphere countries?  A beach ball icon instead of a snowflake?   (IIRC Steam actually does have a different page fro "Summer sale" for us in the South (of the globe))

Comment: "New Year bash" is a much better alternative in my opinion, since it is the time close to the beginning of a new year in Gregorian calendar, which is an international standard.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure why this was down-voted so much. Here's the current weather where I am:

[image]

Yeah, it'll hit 90F by noon tomorrow. We might be looking at monsoons over the holiday. I'm roasting a prime rib, four chickens and breaking down a salmon. It's hot in the kitchen.

But Stack Exchange doesn't live close to the equator; nor do most people that use it. We had to pick a name, and "Winter Bash" is a fine one. It's all about having fun at the end of the year - even when winter is in very short supply where you live.

I mean, just look:

[image]

That's me running like heck after overworking my freezer for ammo.

The name isn't meant to exclude anyone, it's simply saying:

*We want to have some fun, would you like to join us, wherever you are?*

We could call it our yearly bash, but we kinda already do that, since we do it every year.

Trying to home the name based on location would be a disaster, especially if you live in Guam or some other place where GeoIP databases tend to stay stale for really long periods of time.

"Holiday Bash" automatically excludes everyone that doesn't celebrate the holiday.

What can I say? The planet tilts, we have to cope.

Comment: I read that as 77C, I gasped for a moment

Comment: Every! Body! Gets! A Moustache?

Comment: We need SUMMER SMASH